# Converting Populate Output to Entities Pattern ( key/value)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, nosql

So I have 3 models in MongoDB that I'm trying to get a specific behavior out of and I'm struggling on it a bit.

I have it so I can add or remove students to courses and it will update the arrays on both ends. Likewise for adding and removing courses.

What I'm trying to do now is to query everything in the courseIds array and return a Set of all the students across all the courses that belong to a teacher.

I've spent a decent chunk of time trying to get this, but the info around it seems to be sparse as they don't seem to work well with populate.

My Models look like this currently:

```js
const StudentSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true
    },
    age: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    grade: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    notes: {
        type: String
    },
    courseIds: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Course"
        }
    ]
});
```

```js
const CourseSchema = new Schema({
    subject: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    year: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    term: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    period: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    grade: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    teacherId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Teacher"
    },
    studentIds: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Student"
        }
    ]
});
```

```js
const TeacherSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true
    },
    courseIds: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Course"
            // autopopulate: true
        }
    ]
});
```

I'm using express and my request looks like this so far:

```js
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    Teacher.findById(req.body.teacher._id)
        .populate({
            path: "courseIds",
            select: ["subject", "year", "term", "period", "grade", "teacherId"]
        })
        .exec((err, teacher) => {
            console.log(teacher);
            let payload = {
                teachers: {
                    [teacher._id]: {
                        _id: teacher._id,
                        name: teacher.name,
                        email: teacher.email
                    }
                },
                courses: indexPayload(teacher.courseIds)
            };
            res.json(payload);
        });
});
```

The current response looks like this. Its very intentional as I plan to plug this into a react/redux cycle and want to use an entities pattern.

Is there any way to do this in a single query or am I looking at querying each individual course and returning the Set?

```
{
    "teachers": {
        "5d904a0da0383e1cd80cd095": {
            "_id": "5d904a0da0383e1cd80cd095",
            "name": "Teacher Name",
            "email": "teacher.name@awesomeschool.com"
        }
    },
    "courses": {
        "5d904a3126b2641d5223be6c": {
            "_id": "5d904a3126b2641d5223be6c",
            "subject": "Physics",
            "year": "2018",
            "term": "Spring",
            "period": "1",
            "grade": 3,
            "teacherId": "5d904a0da0383e1cd80cd095"
        },
        "5d904a3326b2641d5223be6e": {
            "_id": "5d904a3326b2641d5223be6e",
            "subject": "Physics",
            "year": "2018",
            "term": "Spring",
            "period": "1",
            "grade": 3,
            "teacherId": "5d904a0da0383e1cd80cd095"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally I would do this kind of *tranform* on the **client** instead. The main reason being that the conversion to an *entities pattern* is actually **expanding** the data returned and thus sent over the network. Greater size means greater cost$$. It is *"possible"* to do using the Aggregation Framework if your MongoDB version supports it, but again I would not *personally advise* such an action for the very reasons mentioned.

Comment: Also FYI, due to the singular nature of the request ( one teacher as a separate response and a separate key for the list of courses ) you might also consider instead to make these **two** separate requests API code as well. The `populate()` method actually does invoke those requests separately anyway, but there is actually a **lot** of internal logic *"under the hood"* happening which you are then deliberately undoing by process of your transformation. So it actually would be more efficient *on the server* to do those requests from each collection separately and in **parallel** yourself.

Comment: For example the **parallel** requests would look like `Promise.all([Teacher.findById(req.body.teacher._id), Course.find({ teacherId: req.body.teacher._id)]).then(([teacher, courses]) => res.json({ teachers: { [teacher._id]: teacher }, courses: indexPayload(courses) }))`. This would be better both in the requests from `populate()` are actually in **series** and therefore wait for the first to complete before fetching the "related", which is not necessary here. Additionally, a **lot** of work is done to "merge" those results, which we can determine is exactly the opposite of the wanted result.

Comment: To be clear this specific response is designed to grab a bulk of the relevant information on login and the remaining stuff just augments it. 

So that paralell promise, how exactly does the syntax on that work and where would that fall into my code. I currently have an external apiutil file that has some of the snippets I might need to call from different controllers.

Comment: the current call is built like this: 

```js
Teacher.findById(req.body.teacher._id)
  .populate({
   path: "courseIds",
   select: ["subject", "year", "term", "period", "grade", "teacherId"]
  })
  .exec((err, teacher) => {
   if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
   let payload = {
    teachers: {
     [teacher._id]: {
      _id: teacher._id,
      name: teacher.name,
      email: teacher.email
     }
    },
    courses: indexPayload(teacher.courseIds),
    students: indexStudents(teacher.courseIds)
   };
   res.json(payload);
  });
});
```

Comment: If you actually read all of what I wrote, I gave you the code for that already. Note also that the `select` on the `populate()` serves no purpose since you are just "selecting all the fields", and that's the *default* action with MongoDB anyway.

Comment: I know. I meant the logic of the syntax since I've never even seen Promise.all before, but I'll just look at the docs. I am not selecting all fields, I just trimmed the non-relevant code. The whole goal of shaping the data on the backend was specifically to minimize the size of the response considering there's a decent chunk of duped data by the nature of Mongo being non-relational. eg: A teacher can teach the same kid for 4 years in 3 classes a year. I don't need to include an array of all the students in each class. Just an array for every student of the classes they took with that teacher.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help thought! I'm going to have fun looking into parallel Promises. I'm just on a time crunch now. I did find a solution below that returned a pretty large response from the database that I just need to trim down before sending it

Answer (score 0):

So, after much digging I figured it out. I missed part of the docs entirely.

You can nest populates if you shape your database schema correctly. In this case

```js
Teacher.findById(req.body.teacher._id)
        .populate({
            path: "courseIds",
            select: ["subject", "year", "term", "period", "grade", "teacherId"],
            populate: { path: "studentIds", select: [] }
        })
```